# How to use Python in GraalVM

Tags: python, quarkus, graalvm

I would like to run a Python script inside GraalVM by using the Quarkus framework.

First, I tested with javascript and I was able to run a js script. Then I move to Python but I'm currently encountering the error:

```
IllegalArugmentException: A language with id 'python' is not installed. Install languages are: [js].
```

But I have installed python in my local GraalVM installation by following this procedure: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/python.

One thing, I use this for js:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a dependency for Python? I tried searching for org.graalvm.python in mvnrepository.com but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: This really looks like you don't have Python installed. Are you sure it's installed? Note that if you are building native image of your application, you need to add `--language:python`

Comment: You can verify by checking contents of `$GRAALVM_HOME/jre/languages` or `$GRAALVM_HOME/languages` for JDK11 or later. It should contain `python` folder.